# UIImageView border-radius

Tags: ios, pixate

I'm trying to style a UIImageView using pixate 2.0.1.

---

Without styling the image looks like this:

[image]

---

After applying the style bellow I get this output:

[image]

---

```
.image-photo{
   border: 1px solid #0c0;
   border-radius: 45px;
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue here. Setting borders and radius in images actually replaces the UIImageView.image by a new one. This is a terrible approach because then we lose the previously loaded image, and it also does not mask to the radous shape. Any solution found so far?

Comment: I created the issue in their Github page, lets see if they have a solution... https://github.com/Pixate/PixateFramework/issues/3

Comment: If anyone interested, I hacked into the Pixate library to add the cornerRadius property into views that have the border-radius css style. You can include it by adding this into your porject https://gist.github.com/angelolloqui/8976802. I have not tested it with images, so if it doesnt work you probably need to change PXUIView by PXUIImageView

Answer (score 0):

Even though [the documentation](http://www.pixate.com/docs/framework/ios/latest/style-reference/controls/uiimageview.html) says you can apply `border-radius` and other border effects to `UIImageView`, I don't think you really can without losing your image.

I recommend placing a `UIView` there, assigning it a `styleClass` and then putting your `UIImageView` inside it. You can then reliably apply styles to the `UIView` and get the background and border effects you want around the image.

**Update**

There is also an issue with your CSS syntax. Pixate doesn't support the shorthand border notation. You have to write it like this:

```
.image-photo{
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:#0c0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-radius:45px;
}
```

Again, this has to go on a `UIView` that contains the `UIImageView`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Clifton. It still doesn't work. If I assign the class to a view it works but if I put the image inside the view it doesnt mask to bounds and I get the square UIImageView instead of a UIImageView with rounded corners

Comment: Hi again same issue, if I set those values to the UIview the UIImageView still displays without border-radius. BTW I think that shorthand border notation works, but when it sets the border-radius to  the view it doesn't mask the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You need set your image via CSS. If you want to do it in code, then you can use the styleCSS property.